# Как создать ссылку на профиль пользователя вида account/user/

Tags: python, django, d

Создал личный кабинет вида сайт/account/

**Не получается создать личный кабинет вида account/user/**

**user - пользователь, который зашел**

Модель

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[self.user])
```

Вьюха

```
def profile_user(request, user):

    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', {'profile': 'profile'})
```

urls

```
path('<slug:user>/', views.profile_user, name='profile'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter()` возвращает Queryset. А вам нужен сам объект. Используйте `.get()` вместо `.filter()`

Answer (score 1):

ты во вью пытаешься получить текущего пользователя, а тебе нужно найти пользователя, имя которого совпадает с параметром  `user`  + возможно заменить `.filter` на `.get` в зависимости от того, как ты хочешь работать в `html` шаблоне

```
def profile_user(request, user):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=user)
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', {'profile': 'profile'})
```